# Border class in semantic UI

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

In boostrap i could easily do {border border-primary or border-top-0} how do i achieve this with semantic UI via a built-in class.

I tried dabbling thorough the docs

```
<div id="Tab" class="ui centered aligned container">
  <h1></h1>
div
```

I would love a border on the h1 element

Answer (score 1):

Semantic UI dont have build in class for border (you can check Semantic UI document)

You can create a class use format with

- First param is the thick of border
- Second is line type
- Third is border color.

  .border-1{
     border: 1px solid green;
  }

Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

```css
.border-1{
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="Tab" class="ui centered aligned container">
  <h1 class='border-1'>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: yea thanks I know that. I was thinking there was a built-in class for this in semantic UI

Comment: Just mentioning for folks new to CSS/HTML: to specify a border you *need* to have the pixels, the border type, and the color, as in the example above: "1px solid green".  If you specify for example just "1px", you won't get a border.